# Can I check if a variable can be cast to a specified type?

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to verify whether a variable that is passed can be converted to a specific type.  I have tried the following but can't get it to compile so I assume I'm going about it the wrong way (I'm new to C#)

```
string myType = "System.Int32";
string myValue = "42";

bool canBeCast = false;

try
{
  // try to convert the value to it's intended type to see if it's valid.
  var result = (Type.GetType(typeString))dataValue;
  canBeCast = true;
}
catch
{
  canBeCast = false;
}
```

I'm basically trying to avoid a massive switch statement along the lines of

```
  switch(myType){
    case "System.Int32":
      try
      {
        var convertedValue = Convert.ToInt32(myValue);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        canBeConverted = false;
      }
      break;
    case "another type":
      ...
  }
```

EDIT:

Ok, basically I have a db table of known input types that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MetadataTypes] (
    [typeName]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [dataType]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [typeRegex] VARCHAR (255) NULL
);
```

which may have data such as

```
"StartTime","System.DateTime",null
"TicketId","System.String","$[Ff][0-9]{7}^"
```

And the input to my function would be a KeyValuePair along the lines of

```
myInput = new KeyValuePair<string,string>("StartTime","31/12/2010 12:00");
```

I need to check that the value of the KeyValuePair is of the correct datatype expected by the MetaDataType.

EDIT FOR ANSWER:

Leon got really close to the solution I finally came up with.

For reference my function now looks like this:

```
public Boolean ValidateMetadata(KeyValuePair<string, string> dataItem)
{

  // Look for known metadata with name match
  MetadataType type = _repository.GetMetadataTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.typeName == dataItem.Key);
  if (type == null) { return false; }

  // Get the data type and try to match to the passed in data item.
  Boolean isCorrectType = false;
  string typeString = type.dataType;
  string dataValue = dataItem.Value;

  try
  {
    var cValue = Convert.ChangeType(dataValue, Type.GetType(typeString));
    isCorrectType = true;
  }
  catch
  {
    isCorrectType = false;
  }

  //TODO: Validate against possible regex here....            

  return isCorrectType;

}
```

Comment: What types of data are you expecting? Which are you required to handle?

Comment: it's not a casting, it's more a converting

Comment: ok, Int32 was only an example of a type I might be trying to validate. It could be DateTime, Boolean, Decimal, etc.

Comment: @Nick: If you're always coming **from** `string`, you'll need to parse. You should have some idea what type you **want** it to be, which is where you're use the `TryParse` method of each type you mentioned.

Comment: Alas, Convert.ChangeType(object, type) only works for objects that implement IConvertible

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use the "as" operator to attempt a cast:

```
var myObject = something as String;

if (myObject != null)
{
  // successfully cast
}
else
{
  // cast failed
}
```

If the cast fails, no exception is thrown, but the destination object will be Null.

**EDIT:**

if you know what type of result you want, you can use a helper method like this:

```
public static Object TryConvertTo<T>(string input)
{
    Object result = null;
    try
    {
        result = Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Similar to `is`, you can't just cast `string` to `int`. This will fail every time even if parsing would succeed.

Comment: Your edit got very close to my solution :)  I just needed to get the type to convert to from it's name.

Comment: @yoyo The "as" operator DOES attempt a cast. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx). The ["is" operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) is the one that doesn't convert.

Comment: The as operator only works for reference or nullable types, so that solution doesn't cover all the cases.

Comment: @Leon he means explicit conversions -- `as` will only attempt to "cast" to a compatible type -- it won't actually *convert* an int to a string (even if you box it) -- `as` doesn't return a new / converted object. -- It just returns the same object with a different type handle (or null if it can't be cast).

Comment: @yoyo Feel free to delete your erroneous comment to prevent future readers from getting wrong information.

Comment: @Stefnotch good idea. Unfortunately I can't delete the other comments about my erroneous comment, so now the thread is a little confusing.

Answer (score 21):

Checkout this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.71).aspx

> The is operator is used to check whether the run-time type of an object is compatible with a given type. The is operator is used in an expression of the form:

```
if (expression is type){
    // do magic trick
}
```

Something you can use?

Comment: The `is` operator won't work in this case because a `string` is a completely different type from `int`.

Comment: If you know what type it is, why bother parsing?

Comment: @321X, parsing a number isn't about figuring out what type *it is*, but what type *you want it to be.*

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
return myType.IsInstanceOfType(myObject);
```

Comment: This was perfect for my purposes.  I'm writing an MVC validator and needed to check if a value passed into my validator IsValid function was of a given (possibly nullable) type.

Comment: if `myObject` is `null`, this will return `true`. `is` might be a better check (depending on the case), or simply also remember to validate the `null` case.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var myValue = "42";
int parsedValue;

if (Int32.TryParse(myValue, out parsedValue)) {
    // it worked, and parsedValue is equal to 42
}
else {
    // it did not work and parsedValue is unmodified
}
```

**EDIT**: Just to be clear, the operators `is` and `as` are used in the following ways...

The `is` operator will return a `boolean` value to indicate whether or not the object being tested either *is* the type specified or implements the interface specified. It's like asking the compiler "Is my variable this type?":

```
var someString = "test";
var result = someString is IComparable; // result will be true
```

The `as` operator attempts to perform the conversion, and returns a `null` reference if it can't. This is like telling the compiler "I would like to use this variable as this type":

```
var someString = "test";
var comparable = someString as IComparable; // comparable will be of type String
```

If you tried to do this:

```
var someString = "42";
// using Int32? because the type must be a reference type to be used with as operator
var someIntValue = someString as Int32?;
```

The compiler will issue an error:

> Cannot convert type via a built-in converstion.

Answer (score 3):

From C#7 You can use new switch with pattern matching (https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

```
        switch (myObject)
        {
            case PlayerObject playerObject:
                //this is player object type and can use also playerObject because it's already casted
                break;
            case EnemyObject enemyObject:
                //same here but we have enemy object type
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) which has a boolean return value to indicate whether the conversion succeeded

Comment: So you're suggesting `TryTryParse()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `int.TryParse()` function:

```
int myInt;
bool parsed = int.TryParse(myVariable, out myInt);

if (parsed) {
    // Do something with myInt or other logic
}
```