# Typecasting an object in C#

Tags: c#

Assume I have a method which returns object of class A

`A getItem(int index)`

Now I have following line of code, (I assume `B` is subclass of `A`)

`B b = (B) obj.getItem(i);`

but before this I have to make sure that I can typecast it into `B` as `getItem` can return object of some other subclass, say `C`, of `A`

Something like this

```
    if(I can typecast obj.getItem(i) to B) {
             B b = (B) obj.getItem(i);
    }
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Here is a useful link: :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042314/can-i-check-if-a-variable-can-be-cast-to-a-specified-type

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

```
object item = obj.getItem(i); // TODO: Fix method naming...
// Note: redundancy of check/cast
if (item is B)
{
    B b = (B) item;
    // Use b
}
```

Or:

```
object item = obj.getItem(i); // TODO: Fix method naming...
B b = item as B;
if (item != null)
{
    // Use b
}
```

See ["Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr/496167#496167) for a more detailed comparison between the two.

Answer (score 2):

```
var item = obj.GetItem(i);
if(item is B) {
   B b = (B) item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `as` instead:

```
B b = obj.getItem(i) as B;
if(b != null)
    // cast worked
```

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, **if the conversion isn't possible, `as` returns `null` instead of raising an exception**.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `as` keyword. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

```
Base b = d as Base;
if (b != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
}
```